# How to obtain storage options from Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

I am writing template function which should take some `Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>` as input, perform some computations, and then return new eigen value. I want to return value with same storage order as input.

But i have no idea how to obtain storage order from `Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>`. What can i do in this situation, and is it possible at all? I know that i can pass storage order as another template parameter, or receive `Eigen::Matrix<InpScalar, InpStatRows, InpStatCols, InpStorageOrder>`, but i want avoid it, if it possible

PS Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Are you sure thats what you want? `MatrixBase` serves as a base class for *"any matrix, vector, or expression"* ([source](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html)) and therefore matrix-specific options for storage order aren't applicable

Comment: @kmdreko i'm agree, probably it's a bad idea. Btw, it's possible to obtain data pointer from MatrixBase<Derived> via .derived(). So maybe it's possible to extract storage order too

Comment: @kmdreko do you know how to declare template function which receives general eigen matrix without specifying all it's template arguments? (scalar, rows, cols, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the storage order of `MatrixBase<Derived>`, you can check the `IsRowMajor` enum:

```
int const StorageOrder = Derived::IsRowMajor ? Eigen::RowMajor : Eigen::ColMajor;
```

If you want to have a type with the same storage order and same size as `Derived` you can directly use `typename Derived::PlainObject` (or `PlainMatrix`):

```
template<class Derived>
typename Derived::PlainObject foo(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> & input)
{
   typename Derived::PlainObject return_value;
   // do some complicated calculations
   return return_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To respond to you comment on how to declare a function which receives a general matrix you can do something like this:

Since functions (and methods) deduce their template parameters from their actual function parameter like below

```
template <typename InpScalar, int InpStatRows, int InpStatCols, int InpStorageOrder>
void foo(Eigen::Matrix<InpScalar, InpStatRows, InpStatCols, InpStorageOrder>& matrix)
{
    //you can utilize InpStorageOrder here
}
```

The template parameters of the `matrix` input parameter will be automatically deduced, meaning that you don't have to specify them explicitly when you call the function, just pass it any `Eigen::Matrix`

An example on how to call the function from another function

```
void bar()
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> mat;
    foo(mat);
}
```

If you want just to get the storage order an given matrix, if nothing exists in the `Eigen` library already to do this then you can implement a type trait for Eigen matrices

```
template <typename TMatrix>
struct MatrixTraits {};

//Partial specialization of MatrixTraits class template
//will accept only `Eigen::Matrix` classes as its template argument
template <typename InpScalar, int InpStatRows, int InpStatCols, int InpStorageOrder>
struct MatrixTraits<Eigen::Matrix<InpScalar, InpStatRows, InpStatCols, InpStorageOrder>>
{
    int StorageOrder = InpStorageOrder;
};
```

To utilize this you can do it like:

```
void bar()
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> mat;
    int StorageOrder = MatrixTraits<decltype(mat)>::StorageOrder;
}
```

Comment: The fourth template parameter of `Eigen::Matrix` also contains information about alignment. And you don't need to implement these traits yourself for what the OP wants to do.